# Prove that $\exp(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n}) = \frac{1}{1-z} \; \forall z \in \mathbb{C}: \; |z| < 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

> Prove that $\exp(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n}) = \frac{1}{1-z} \; \forall z \in \mathbb{C}: \; |z| < 1$

I know that $f = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n}$ converges absolutely for all $z \in \mathbb{C} ;\ |z| < 1$ and is analytic. My idea was to show that the coefficients of the Taylorseries of $\exp(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n})$ at $z_0 = 0$ are all equal to one, which would mean that $\exp(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n}) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty z^k = \frac{1}{1-z}$.
I got $f^{k}(0) = (k-1)!$.
But I got stuck after calculating the first few derivatives, because after applying the chain rule a few times they get kinda complicated... And I am not quite sure anymore if Im taking the right approach.

I was hoping somebody could maybe help me out/ give me a hint on how to proceed

Comment: the series is the very well-known Mercator series, that is, $\sum_{n\geqslant 1}\frac{z^n}{n}=-\log(1-z)$ for all $|z|\leqslant 1$ except $z=1$

Answer (score 3):

If you don't know the beautiful Identity theorem yet, let's try to do it your way. Let $$f : z \mapsto \sum_{n= 1}^{\infty} \dfrac{z^n}{n}$$
which is analytic on the open disk. Then $g = \exp \circ f$ is also analytic, and $g' = f' (\exp' \circ f) = f'g$. Besides, derivating $f$ term by term yields, $$f'(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z^n = \dfrac{1}{1-z}.$$

It follows that for $n \geq 0$, with a simple induction,
$$ f^{(n+1)}(z) = \dfrac{n!}{(1-z)^n } \qquad f^{(n+1)}(0) = n!$$

Now we will prove by strong induction on $k \geq 0$ the statement $\mathcal{P}(k) : g^{(k)}(0) = k!. $

- **Base case** : for $k = 0$ then $g^{(0)}(0) = g(0) = \exp(f(0)) = \exp(0) = 1 = 0!$
- **Induction step** : we assume $\mathcal{P}(0),\dots, \mathcal{P}(k)$ to be true, we want to prove $\mathcal{P}(k+1)$. Using the general Leibniz rule yields
  $$g^{(k+1)} = (g')^{(k)} = (f'g)^{(k)}  = \sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j} (f')^{(j)} g^{(k-j)}  $$
  by assumption $g^{(k-j)}(0) = (k-j)!$ and you know that $(f')^{(j)}(0) = j!$. Hence,
  $$g^{(k+1)}(0) = \sum_{j=0}^k \dfrac{k!}{j! (k-j)!} \cdot j! \cdot (k-j)! = \sum_{j=0}^k k! = k! (k+1) = (k+1)!$$
  whence $\mathcal{P}(k+1)$.
- **Conclusion** : since both the base case and the induction step have been proved as true, by mathematical induction the statement $\mathcal{P}(k)$ holds for every natural number $k$.

Therefore,
$$\boxed{ \forall |z|<1, \; g(z) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{g^{(k)}(0)}{k!} z^k = \sum_{k= 0}^{\infty} z^k = \dfrac{1}{1-z}}$$

Answer (score 2):

$\exp(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n}) =\exp (-\ln (1-x))=\frac 1 {1-x}$ for $0<x<1$. Both sides of your equation are analytic in the open unit disk and they are equal on a set with a limit point. Hence they are equal on the disk by the Identity Theorem.

[This argument does not require any knowledge of logarithms in the complex plane].

Comment: The Identity Theorem is only introduced in the next chapter, so I think this exercise can be proven without it. But thanks, this proof makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Write $f(z) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n}$. Using the identity $f'(z) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} z^{n-1} = \frac{1}{1-z}$ for $|z| < 1$, we find that

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z} \left[ (1 - z) e^{f(z)} \right] = - e^{f(z)} + (1-z)f'(z)e^{f(z)} = 0. $$

Since the unit disk $\mathbb{D}$ is a domain (open, connected subset) of $\mathbb{C}$, the fundamental theorem of calculus shows that $(1 - z)e^{f(z)} $ is constant on $\mathbb{D}$. Then the value of this constant can be determined by plugging $z = 0$, yielding

$$ (1 - z) e^{f(z)} = 1 $$

for all $z \in \mathbb{D}$. Therefore the desired claim follows.